# Thoughts about timestamps in SQL, compare current year

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

How do I get the rows that has the year 2014 and compare it like a timestamp value?

Code here:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt, '%Y') AS tidpunkt 
FROM ringupp WHERE tidpunkt == "CURRENT YEAR IN TIMESTAMP 2014";
```

Comment: @Kermit: Sorry, I have edit my question.

Comment: What is the data type of `tidpunkt`?

Comment: @Kermit: The data type is Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `YEAR`:

```
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt)) = 2014
```

Comment: Im trying with this query: SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt , '%Y') AS tidpunkt, REPLACE(telnr,'-', '') as telnr FROM ringupp WHERE (telnr LIKE '%$p1%' AND '$p1' <> '') OR (telnr LIKE '%$p2%' AND '$p2' <> '') OR (telnr LIKE '%$p3%' AND '$p3' <> '') AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tidpunkt)) = 2014 This should only renturns the rows that has 2014, but it returns ALL the rows, even the rows that has 2013.

Comment: Try adding parentheses around all your `OR`'s ... `WHERE ( .. OR .. OR .. OR .. ) AND ..`

Comment: Thank you very much. Why parentheses?

Comment: @user500468 [Order precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)